# How to change reCAPTCHA error message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to change the reCAPTCHA default error message that says:

> The verification words are incorrect.

I installed my reCAPTCHA from this tutorial: http://blog.tkglaser.net/2011/10/google-recaptcha-in-aspnet-mvc-3-using.html

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to do it in the View.
Just like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha("captcha", "clean"))
  @Html.ValidationMessage("captcha", "Whatever message you want to type")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to AccountController.cs -> Register method, and just modify this:

```
if (!captchaValid)
    ModelState.AddModelError("captcha", captchaErrorMessage);
```

to this:

```
if (!captchaValid)
    ModelState.AddModelError("captcha", "whatever message you want to type");
```